# Change index value in generator expression python

Tags: python, iterator, conditional-statements, expression, generator

i'm new to python and I'm trying to do a condition inside a generator expression, and if my condition is met, I want to divide the index by 2, and add the index to a list. Else, i want to multiply by 3 and add 1. Also the order needs to be from n to 1. I cant really figure out where I update the index.
My code so far as follows:

```
def foo(n):
print(list(i // 2 if i % 2 == 0 else i * 3 + 1 for i in reversed(range(n + 1))))
```

Assuming n=5, output should be:

```
[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

My output:

```
[16, 2, 10, 1, 4, 0]
```

I saw that you can iterate using something like:

```
for i in range(start, end, -1)
```

How do I change the " -1 " to match my condition? (i=i/2 in case of even number, i*3+1 else).
Or I'm completely off course in which case I would like a hint. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a great use case for a generator expression. Just write an explicit loop.

Comment: The index is updated in the "for i in reversed..." part. If you think this is what you need, you should be able to change it  to be "reversed(range(0, n+1, -1))". Also good luck with the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: Agreeing with @user2357112supportsMonica, while a single line might look pretty, it won't really run faster and it will be easier to read as an explicit loop.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree it's not a great use case but is it possible to do?